# a-frame networked - how to match an avatar with a broadcasting client?

Tags: aframe, aframe-networked

I'm using [aframe-networked](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe), and I'm sending some custom data between the users:

```
// sender
NAF.connection.broadcastDataGuaranteed(dataType, data)
// all recipients listen
NAF.connection.subscribeToDataChannel(dataType, (senderId, type, data, target) => {})
```

but I'm having trouble determining which avatar entity is corresponding to the broadcasting client. How the receivers know which player is the `sender` from the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be by using `aframe-networked` [events](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe#events), and keeping all connected users in a dictionary. The `creatorID`, `ownerId` and `networkId` are all kept in the `networked` component - so all You need is to grab them once the avatar is created:

```
const usersMap = {};

// Fired when a networked entity is created 
document.body.addEventListener("entityCreated", function(evt) {
  const networkedComponent = evt.detail.el.getAttribute("networked");
  usersMap[networkedComponent.creator] = {
    networkId: networkedComponent.networkId,
    el: evt.detail.el
  };
});

// Fired when another client disconnects from you   
document.body.addEventListener("clientDisconnected", function(evt) {
  if (usersMap[evt.detail.clientId]) delete usersMap[evt.detail.clientId];
});
```

Now, each time You get a callback from a broadcasted message (via `NAF.connection.subscribeToDataChannel(dataType, callback)`) You can easily track the entity belonging to the sender:

```
// change the senders color to blue
NAF.connection.subscribeToDataChannel("data", (sender, type, data, target) => {
  usersMap[sender].el.setAttribute("color", "blue");
})
```

You can see it working in [this glitch](https://aframe-networked-broadcastingdata.glitch.me/). If any user presses "excuse me" the rest should see an exclamation mark above his head.

---

If You're broadcasting data in another way (like another `socket.io` connection), You can pass Your own `clientID` (`player.getAttribute("networked").creator`) in the message, so the above stays the same,

**or** you can pass the `networkId`, so the receiver can do a single query:

```
 let senderEntity = document.getElementById("naf-" + networkId)
```

Comment: Posted this because [this comment discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444383/2425787) was heading in this direction. I'd appreciate any comment if the answer is clear.